# How to restrict users to single VPC in Google cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, access-control, google-iam, google-vpc

If I have 2 VPCs set up for 2 different teams on a single project in GCP and want to give the IAM users the access to one single VPC and the resources in that VPC only, how to I do that in Google cloud platform? what IAM roles has to be assigned to these users?

Comment: The correct isolation to use is separate projects and not permissions to VPCs. Anything else will require complexity that is easy to configure wrong or not at all. Review if your developers actually need IAM access. Some developers only need SSH access to VMs to do their jobs.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply. These developers need IAM access. Also there are other resources like Storage bucket , k8s clusters with the VPCs other than the VMs. and if VPC access could grant/revoke/restrict access to all other resources in that VPC it would have been useful as there are few such VPCs and resources in a single project.

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve this easily and out of the box. The VPC is a resource, you can restrict access on this resource. VM (on this VPC) are also resources, and the permissions provided on the VPC aren't inherited to the resource that use this VPC.

You can to use a new feature, named [asset relationship](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/asset-relationships) that provide you the relation between the assets. Like that you could get the asset (resources) in relation with your VPC and enforce the same restriction on all these resources. But you need to code this, it's not out of the box, and the feature still in preview.